# How to change header text in DatagridView - in code C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to change header text in `DatagridView` and how to add or remove column - in C# code?

Comment: Is it really too much trouble to add a [WinForms] tag?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are using data-binding to a type and auto-generated columns, this is the `[DisplayName(...)]`, i.e.

```
[DisplayName("Last name")]
public string LastName {get;set;}
```

Otherwise this is the `HeaderText` on the column, i.e.

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Something special";
```

A basic way to add a column is:

```
int columnIndex = grid.Columns.Add("columnName", "Header Text");
```

Or you can be more specific, for example to add a column of hyperlinks:

```
grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewLinkColumn());
```

(you could obviously set more properties on the new column first)

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.6.1 and my Datagrid.Columns[0] doesn't have HeaderText property.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colName", "colHeaderText");
```

This is the simplest method for adding a column and setting it's header text, although it might be much more useful to follow @Marc Gravell's advice if you want the column to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked for me...

dataGridView1.Columns[datagridview1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "newHeaderText";