# Change column Heading names in DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I am working on a .NET project where I am trying to change the column heading names in datagridview but for unknown reason I am still unable to do so . Can anyone help me out in this matter

Below is the code and markup for the datagridview that I am using :

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(539, 36);
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(936, 353);
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 9;
```

code :

```
string query = "SELECT $_LastSaleDate AS 'Last_Sale_Date', $_LastSaleParty AS 'last sale to party', $_LastSalePrice AS 'last sold price', $Name AS 'name of party', $_ClosingBalance AS 'closing balance' FROM  ItemMovementAnalysis WHERE ($_ClosingBalance = 1511)  AND ($_LastSalePrice = 25) AND ($_LastSaleParty = 'Sumandeep Ji ( Punjab )') and ($_LastSaleDate = '09 Aug 2022') ";
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, con)) 
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dadapter.Fill(table);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: @DaleK                                              
  this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(539, 36);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(936, 353);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 9;

Comment: @DaleK , sorry i dont understand what you mean to say .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change header text in DatagridView - in code C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486482/how-to-change-header-text-in-datagridview-in-code-c)

Comment: @NagibMahfuz , sir i actually was looking for a way to change the header name via sql query which I have used .

Comment: What column headers are you getting? @DaleK Yes this should be possible . The DataGridView should automatically set the Column header as the aliased names in the SQL.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , i am getting $_LastSaleDate instead of Last_Sale_Date . like this all of my columns headers are not changing

Comment: Why are you using OdbcDataAdapter? You should be using SqlDataAdapter. Odbc is more restricted.

Comment: The driver is probably the issue.  What driver are you using in the connection string?

Comment: @jdweng         string source = "DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;DSN = TallyODBC_9000; SERVER = (local); PORT = 9000;Uid=admin;Pwd=admin;option=16";// be careful for spacees

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , my datasource is in ODBC

Comment: But you have tagged sql server, so why aren't you using a sql connection string instead of odbc?

Comment: Do you see the headers already in designtime ? In that case, remove the columns in designtime and set the property to allow to add columns

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , sir I am new to programming . Can i use sqlconnection string and sqldataadapter when my database server is ODBC ?

Comment: Please do not show such information from your connection string here in public, that is never save. Also, why would you use ODBC to connect to a sql-server database ?

Comment: @GuidoG my database is in odbc

Comment: The problem is occurring the TallyODBC_9000 driver.  An ODBC driver is older than OLEDB and the SQLClient and is less compatible than the other drivers but runs much quicker.  The driver isn't doing the column name substitution.  You can instead change the names in the DataTable.

Comment: ODBC is not a database, it is an ancient method to connect to a database. For SQL server I use `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`, you can also use a newer driver like `SQL Server NativeClient XX.X`

Comment: I suggest you do the following, create an empty text file anywhere, and rename it so the extension is `.UDL` Now doubleclick on that file, the `Data Link Properties` window should now appear, use this to build and test a connection to your database, after you have done so, open the file in notepad and you will find a good working connection string

Comment: Try looking [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) There are lots of examples to help you